# How to bake without overlapping textures

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, baking

I have an object with multiple materials. All these materials have their own textures and their UV maps overlaps. How can I bake without editing textures and not overlapping textures?

Comment: [My answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50658/2217) on using multiple UV maps may also be helpful to you.

Comment: Hi David, with my all respect, the answer you linked is not solving my problem. I need to move my UV without loosing their texture. Can you unmark my question, there may be people out there with different ideas. Thanks you so much for your time.

Comment: do you want to combine all those UV maps and textures into one UV map and one texture?

Comment: @Valamor, Blender's texture atlas functionality should do the trick.

Comment: @R00t yes, I need one .png file that includes my textures and after that I will use it in my game engine. But the thing is, my UV maps are overlapping. So that my baked .png file is not correct.

Comment: @Valamor: I still recommend blender's texture atlas feature since it is exactly what you need. In this answer I explained how to use manual mode. [http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51659/texture-baking-and-existing-uv-maps/51677#51677]