# How to texture a huge number of meshes in one uv?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm making a car model for a game with interactable interior, so i have all buttons, pedals and other moveble objects as separate objects. How could i wrap them all into one UV map to texture them later?

Comment: You may join the objects with *Ctrl+J*, then unwrap it and finally bake their textures to one single image. Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57944/bake-taxtures-to-one-image

Comment: @PaulGonet - That's how we old folks did it in the times, before the texture atlas addon was a thing :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get the UVs of all meshes of a complex model into one UV map would be using the Texture Atlas addon. It's in Blender's Community Addon Catalog and can be activated in "User Preferences - Add-ons" (Search for "atlas").

[image]

Once activated, you can find it in "Properties Window - Render - Texture Atlas".

For an in-depth tutorial I recommend watching [Gleb Alexandrow's great tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXyVQ87Hius) on how to use the add-on.

**In case you already have separate UV maps, I'd use the settings I described in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51659/texture-baking-and-existing-uv-maps/51677#51677)**.

The difference between the add-on and Paul Gonet's method is that the major part of the tedious "join - unwrap - separate" process will be done automatically.

Comment: Samrt UV randomize my UV, so it's too hard to find what is what on it (

Comment: Even parts of one mesh being separated to opposite corners of UV ;((

Comment: @Stanislav - check the second link in my answer. It's there for a purpose.

Comment: Oooooooh, ii see. But anyways i almost re umapped this big map :D

Comment: @Stanislav - it's just one method to achieve the goal. I used it to map complex models with up to 150 objects into one UV map. If my answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted".

Comment: Awesome add-on, so usefull and powerfull )